# SQL: Flag Duplicate Records Using Case Statement WHERE FIELD VALUE1 <>FIELD VALUE 2 & FIELD VALUE1 DATE > FIELD VALUE2

Tags: sql, duplicates, subquery, case, distinct

I'm working on a SQL query that counts duplicate records that are based on a text field I am working with: where datasource = 'Web' or 'Internal'. I am currently using a case statement to count the number of times a record shows that value. My question is how do I return values (i'm thinking a case statement with an indicator (1, or 0)) that shows where datasource = 'Web' and date > datasource = 'Internal' and date?

web.datasource date > internal.datasource date

I'm attaching a query of what I currently have working, what my output is and what I would like the end result to look like.

```
SELECT id
,lastname
,firstname
,datasource
,CASE
WHEN (
    (Datasource = 'Web')
    )THEN Count(Datasource)
ELSE 0
    END WebData
,CASE
WHEN (
    (Datasource = 'Internal')
    ) THEN Count(Datasource)
ELSE 0
    END InternalData
,count(id) as countid
,date

FROM Table


GROUP BY
id
,lastname
,firstname
,datasource
,date
```

This currently returns:

```
12345   Jack    Boss    Internal    0   1   1   2015-03-25
12241   Eric    Graves  Internal    0   1   1   2015-04-01
13300   Su      Lynn    Web         1   0   1   2016-02-01
13300   Su      Lynn    Internal    0   1   1   2015-08-07
13914   Mark    Ross    Internal    0   2   2   2015-05-01
14008   Mitch   Smith   Web         1   0   1   2016-03-07
14008   Mitch   Smith   Internal    0   1   1   2015-06-02
```

This is what I would like the end Result to look like:

```
12345   Jack    Boss    Internal    0   1   1   2015-03-25   0
12241   Eric    Graves  Internal    0   1   1   2015-04-01   0
13300   Su      Lynn    Web         1   0   1   2016-02-01   0
13300   Su      Lynn    Internal    0   1   1   2015-08-07   0
13914   Mark    Ross    Internal    0   2   2   2015-05-01   0
14008   Mitch   Smith   Web         1   0   1   2016-03-07   1
14008   Mitch   Smith   Internal    0   1   1   2015-06-02   1
```

OR

```
14008   Mitch   Smith    1   1   2
```

Ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow why it's `0` for all but the last two records in your example, could you explain that?  Perhaps expanding your sample data to show the duplicates would help.  Also, which database are you using?

Comment: Given you are referring to a column `datasource` are you using a `union` to get all the data into one result set?

Comment: I simply put 0,1 as an indicator.  Could be True, False or whatever. 1 Indicates that the web record has a date greater than the internal record

Comment: I could use a union.  Whatever you guys think would/should be used to make the end result look like either one of the two options I posted above.  Haven't had much luck on this one...

Comment: And which database are you using?

Comment: Why aren't the Su Lynn rows marked as well?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```
SELECT id
,lastname
,firstname
,datasource
,CASE
WHEN (
    (Datasource = 'Web')
    )THEN Count(Datasource)
ELSE 0
    END WebData
,CASE
WHEN (
    (Datasource = 'Internal')
    ) THEN Count(Datasource)
ELSE 0
    END InternalData
,count(id) as countid
,date
, sub_table.an_indicator

FROM Table
,   (   select  t2.id as id
,               case when h_table.web_date > h_table.internal_date 
                then 1 
                else 0 end as an_indicator
        from( select t2.id as id
              ,      max( date ) as web_date
              ,      null as internal_date
              from table t2
              where t2.id=Table.id
              and t2.lastname = Table.lastname
              and t2.firstname = Table.firstname
              and t2.datasource = 'Web' 
              group by t2.id
              union
              select t2.id
              ,      null
              ,      max( date ) 
              from table t2
              where t2.id=Table.id
              and t2.lastname = Table.lastname
              and t2.firstname = Table.firstname
              and t2.datasource = 'Internal' 
              group by t2.id
            ) h_table       
    ) sub_table
where sub_table.id = Table.id
```

Comment: It is a good starting point, but I manage to get an error at union distinct, which I can't figure out why i'm getting...?  Logically looking at the query it makes sense.  Not quite sure what my problem is...

Comment: Try leave out distinct... Just union. Just make sure you do not use a union all.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    id, lastname, firstname, datasource
    case when Datasource = 'Web' then count(Datasource) else 0 end as WebData,
    case when Datasource = 'Internal' then count(Datasource) else 0 end as InternalData,
    count(id) as CountId,
    "date",
    min(dups.flag) as dup
from
    <table> as t
    inner join
    (
        select
            id, lastname, firstname,
            case
                when max(case when datasource = 'web' then "date" end) >
                     max(case when datasource = 'internal' then "date" end)
                then 1 else 0
            end as flag
        from <table>
        group by
            id, lastname, firstname
    ) as dups
        on      dups.id = t.id
            and dups.lastname = t.lastname and dups.firstname = t.firstname
group by
    id, lastname, firstname, datasource
```

Any chance this one might work?

```
select
    id, lastname, firstname, datasource
    case when Datasource = 'Web' then count(Datasource) else 0 end as WebData,
    case when Datasource = 'Internal' then count(Datasource) else 0 end as InternalData,
    count(id) as CountId,
    "date",
    case when max(case when datasource = 'web'      then "date" end)
                  over (partition by id, lastname, firstname) >
              max(case when datasource = 'internal' then "date" end)
                  over (partition by id, lastname, firstname)
         then 1
         else 0
    end as dup
from
    <table> as t
group by
    id, lastname, firstname, datasource
```